# Authentication through Loopback4

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, loopback4

I have an API eg. `http://www.myportal.com/login` and when we call this URL it asks for username and password and after successful login, it returns an access token.

Same thing I have to implement in Loopback4 by calling the above URL.

Please give some idea, will appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, what you need to do is do authentication using [passport-local](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local) strategy and then create a [jwt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken) token with authenticated user obtained.

But to do this, you will need to create a separate component with decorators and providers in loopback4. Loopback 4 team is working on ways to provide such features out of the box in the framework. But its not there yet.

We created a loopback extension for the same which supports 4 different passport strategies. You can use that from [here](https://github.com/sourcefuse/loopback4-authentication). Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes Samy you are right. Actually i was doing it through REST connector but due to LB4 limitation i have changed my approach done it through http-request and axios module.
Thanks you your reply :)